# How to extract pip requirements which do not have a wheel?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, requirements.txt

Is there a way to list which of my requirements in my requirements.txt don't have a corresponding wheel?

This sort of works but doesn't seem like a very nice option and takes a lot longer than I would like.

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --force-reinstall | grep '.tar.gz'
```

Comment: What is the goal here? Projects could add a wheel to their releases at any time, and on new major Python releases wheels for that release often lag behind for a while.

Comment: not very elegant, but you can `pip download --no-binary -d some_dir -r requirements.txt` and look what reached some_dir

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry for the slow reply. I am just looking to speed up the build process by changing pinned packages to ones with wheels :)